# Проблема с индексацией в postgres

Tags: postgresql

не получается ускорить БД за счёт индексации.

Создаю таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinate( Id serial primary key,
                                       Lat DECIMAL(9,6),
                                       Lon DECIMAL(9,6));
```

После этого добавляю индексацию:

```
CREATE INDEX indeLat ON coordinate(Lat);
CREATE INDEX indeLon ON coordinate(Lon);
```

Потом идёт заполнение таблицы:

```
INSERT INTO coordinate (Lat, Lon) VALUES(48.685444, 44.474254)
```

Заполняется 100к рандомных координат.

Теперь мне нужно выдать все координаты которые входят в радиус N км от заданной координаты.

```
SELECT id, Lat, Lon
FROM coordinate
WHERE acos(sin(radians(48.704578))*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(radians(48.704578))*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-radians(44.507112))) * 6371 < 50;
```

Время выполнения тестов, примерно равно 0.2сек, причём если не делать **CREATE INDEX** время не изменяется. Подозреваю что ошибка в запросе, может нужно как то перестроить?

Comment: Добавьте `EXPLAIN` перед `SELECT`, оно выдаст план запроса. Там будет видно - используется индекс или нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А каким волшебным образом, вы полагаете, вам здесь могут помочь два btree? На пальцах - каков алгоритм? Правильно, никакой. Единственная возможность - вычислить выражение для каждой строки. Для чего seqscan и выбирается.

В общем случае индекс может использоваться только в выражениях `indexcolumn operator const`. Любой `function(indexcolumn) operator const` индекс по indexcolumn использовать уже не сможет, т.к. где результат этой функции? Его вычислять надо прежде чем сравнивать. (но может - индекс по выражению `function(indexcolumn)` если функция `immutable`)

---

Для адекватного решения задачи поиска по географическим координатам вам нужен [`postgis`](https://postgis.net/) и конкретно функция [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/), а так же [`gist` индекс](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idm1330).

```
select ... from tablename where ST_DWithin(geom, /*ваша geom точка*/, /*радиус*/)
```